# Why is this addition being executed?

Tags: matlab

Why does this happen?

Why does this program give the correct output?

```
a = 5 
c = a + b 
b = 5
```

Output:

```
c = 10
```

Comment: well it seems like `b` is already defined in your workspace so there is no error popping out. Try to `clear` the workspace and then run your code

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because your workspace is not empty at the start of your execution, i.e. `b` was already defined to be `5` before you executed your code.

If you clear your workspace at the beginning, the program will work as expected and return an `Undefined function or variable 'b'` error:

```
clear all;
a = 5 
c = a + b 
b = 5
```